# Cannot install Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver?

Tags: 12.10, broadcom

Being a newbie in Linux, I installed the Wubi version of Ubuntu 12.10 on my Win XP. All is well, except that I have trouble installing the above mentioned driver.

1. Installing from Software Center: when I try to install, I get the message:

   ```
   "Package dependencies could not be installed: bcmwl-kernel-source: depends: dkms: but it will not be installed.
   ```
2. Installing the driver from the Broadcom site: http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php I get the following message during make: `asm/system.h does not exist.`

I would gladly receive advise on what to do next.

Comment: Do you have temporary ethernet access? What is the result of: sudo apt-get install dkms

Comment: Hi, my ethernet access is ok. Answer on sudo apt-get install dkms is : E: cannot find package dkms

Comment: Are you connected to the internet as you try to install these packages? Does it install if you start with: sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install dkms? What is the locale under Software Sources? See here: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_rLKldy7wJfQ/TLxDGPFQu8I/AAAAAAAAAAs/NUpLs-H_16I/s1600/ubuntu-software-sources-proprietary-drivers.jpg You might try another server.

Comment: 1. I am connected to Internet via a second NIC (ethernet card).

Comment: 1.Connected to the Internet via second NIC(ethernet). 2.After apt-get update, dkms installed and after that the bcm-driver was installed via Software Center. OK 3. I configured the wireless network connection (SSID, passwd, DHCP) and tried again, but no Inetconnection.When doing ifconfig, I only see the ethernetcard and local loop, but no wireless card. 4. My questions: how can I test if the wireless driver installed OK? and do I need to specify other params in the network config (like MAC-address,...).