# Cannot install Broadcom STA wireless driver

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 12.0.4 and I cannot get the driver for my Broadcom BCM4311 wireless card installed.

I have searched through the forums and tried many methods including using the Ubuntu Software center, running `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source`, and downloading the driver directly and running `make` - but all of them have failed in a similar manner.

I can post error logs from these and/or any other trials, but this is the one that I find the most telling (from [Cannot install Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278518/cannot-install-broadcom-802-11-linux-sta-wireless-driver)):

```
craig@reaver:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,301 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,656 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 195644 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (from .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-30-generic
Building for architecture i686
Building initial module for 3.8.0-30-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-30-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.20130914, it will be ignored in a future release.
FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic

craig@reaver:~$ sudo modprobe wl
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.20130914, it will be ignored in a future release.
FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

So it seems something is up with this `Module wl`, but I can't figure out exactly what.

UPDATE:
As per rajagenupula's request, here is the ouput of `/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.20.155.1+bdcom for kernel 3.8.0-30-generic (i686)
Sat Sep 14 09:44:57 EDT 2013
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘wl_cfg80211_join_ibss’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:705:26: error: ‘struct cfg80211_ibss_params’ has no member named ‘channel’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1560:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1560:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.scan’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1565:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1565:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.set_tx_power’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1566:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1566:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘wl_cfg80211_ops.get_tx_power’) [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c: In function ‘wl_update_bss_info’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1991:11: error: ‘struct cfg80211_bss’ has no member named ‘information_elements’
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c:1992:15: error: ‘struct cfg80211_bss’ has no member named ‘len_information_elements’
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
```

UPDATE2: In response to ubfan1:

```
craig@reaver:~$ lspci -vvnn |grep 14e4 
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1673] (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
```

I have run `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` and both install just fine.  But I am not sure what to do now.  According to this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx , the b43 driver ought to show up in my 'Additional Drivers' but only the original 'Broadcom STA wireless driver' (which does not install correctly!) is there.  So what is the next step?

Comment: what is the output of /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log

Comment: Updated with the output of make.log, as requested.

Comment: What chip do you have? run lspci -vvnn |grep 14e4 and post the results.  You may have a chip better supported by the b43 driver, for which you will need to add firmware

Comment: I updated the post with the results.